# Docker `No space left on device`

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm having an issue with running docker on a very powerful AWS linux (ubuntu) instance.

When I attempt to pull/extract docker, I get the following error:

`docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /opt/conda/lib/libmkl_mc3.so: no space left on device.`.

I'd like to increase the volume of space that docker is running on in order to allow this file to download (there's plenty of space on the machine as a whole) but I'm unsure how to do this. I've trawled through a number of similar problems on here and none of the provided solutions have proven successful for me.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Output of docker system df:

`TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              0                   0                   0B                  0B
Containers          0                   0                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B`

Comment: what is the output of `docker system df`

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply @ivthillo! Edited into main post.

Comment: The output is strange. This should show the docker disk usage but everything is 0? And there are docker images on your host?

Comment: Full disclosure, I'm a bit of a docker noob. But yes, I think so? This failure occurs when I run `docker pull [args for my docker image]`. One of the things I tried was deleting a lot of docker stuff to try to make more space which may be why values are zero'd here.

Comment: what is the output of sudo systemctl status docker? Is it running fine? And the output of docker images is also empty?

Comment: seems to be running fine -- `Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-10-12 01:36:36 UTC; 17h ago`. Correct, output of docker images is empty. Thanks a ton for the help/insights btw. Can give full output of that command if you're interested but it's a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181778/discussion-between-lvthillo-and-peter-dolan).